# Runtime error when trying to logout django

Tags: python, django, recursion, runtime, logout

When I try to logout from my django project, I get the following error:

"maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Here is the url for the logout button:

```
url(r'^logout', 'users.views.logout', name='logout'),
```

And here is the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from deck1.models import Card
from django.template import RequestContext 
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from users.forms import RegisterForm

@login_required
def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return  HttpResponseRedirect('/deck')
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your view `logout` is overriding the namespace of built-in `logout` function. Define an alias for `django.contrib.auth.login` function using `as` keyword.

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout as django_logout

@login_required
def logout(request):
    django_logout(request)
    return  HttpResponseRedirect('/deck')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return  HttpResponseRedirect('/deck')
```

and according to that change your url

Comment: Can you format your code correctly please

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Kindly change your views function name from logout to any other or import logout by another name.

```py
def logout(request):
    django_logout(request)
    return  HttpResponseRedirect('/deck')
```

You can also just simply change this in your code to resolve this problem.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout as logoutUser
```

Just change this line and your code will run finely. Thanks.